# NSViewController on Mac OS X 10.4

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, memory-management, nib

I am working on a bundle code base—not an app—where development started on 10.4, and is required to run on 10.4, but works all the way up to 10.8. It loads its views from nib files manually and I only just recently realised that there is a substantial memory leak because the nibs utilise bindings and bind against the file's owner, creating reference cycles and preventing the file's owner class from deallocating. I think this is made worse by having the “file's owner” load its own nib.

I load nibs using the following code (this code is in a base class and subclasses override `+nibName`):

```
NSString *nibName = [[self class] nibName];
NSNib *nib = [[NSNib alloc] initWithNibNamed:nibName bundle:myBundle];
[nib instantiateNibWithOwner:self topLevelObjects:&topLevelObjects];
```

Since I have to target 10.4, I am unable to use `NSViewController`. I think I'll need to implement my own view controller class, but how do I prevent the references cycles from happening as the `NSViewController` class promises to do? If the view controller is the nib's “file's owner” won't I instead just be pushing the reference cycles from my current class to my view controllers? What does `NSViewController` do to prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you just use `NSWindowController` or a custom subclass. Your subclass can have a `view` outlet and a KVO-compliant `representedObject` property. That should suffice for a 10.4-compatible replacement.

Answer (score 2):

NSViewController does absolutely nothing special in regards to memory management, or even for top-level objects.  It just provides a safe place to load a nib and then keep its contents in memory for the duration of the Nib's lifecycle, which means the class itself is little more than an external File's Owner.  Just for kicks, I reimplemented the class, and commented out the interesting bits.  Some stuff, I just outright removed because it was so hacky as to not be worth implementing, or so unused that it didn't warrant re-making.  The full class, with documentation and comments, can be found [here](https://github.com/CodaFi/CFIViewController);

```
@interface CFIViewController : NSResponder <NSCoding> {
@private
    NSString *_nibName;
    NSBundle *_nibBundle;
    id _representedObject;
    NSString *_title;
    IBOutlet NSView *view;
    NSArray *_topLevelObjects;
    id _autounbinder; 
    //NSString *_designNibBundleIdentifier;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString*)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil;

- (void)setRepresentedObject:(id)representedObject;
- (id)representedObject;

- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title;
- (NSString *)title;

- (NSView *)view;
- (void)loadView;

- (NSString *)nibName;
- (NSBundle *)nibBundle;

- (void)setView:(NSView *)view;

@end

@implementation CFIViewController

- (void)loadView {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = nil;

    NSNib *loadedNib = [[[NSNib alloc]initWithNibNamed:self.nibName bundle:self.nibBundle]autorelease];
    if (loadedNib == nil) {
        [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"-[%@ %@]", NSStringFromClass(self.class), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)];
        return;
    }

    BOOL loaded = NO;


#if MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_8
    loaded = [loadedNib instantiateWithOwner:self topLevelObjects:&topLevelObjects];
#else 
    loaded = [loadedNib instantiateNibWithOwner:self topLevelObjects:&topLevelObjects];
#endif

    if (loaded) {
        [self _setTopLevelObjects:topLevelObjects];
        [topLevelObjects makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(release)];
    } else {
        [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"CFIViewController could not instantiate the %@ nib.", self.nibName];
    }

    if (self.view != nil) {
        [self viewDidLoad];
        return;
    }

    [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"-[%@ %@]", NSStringFromClass(self.class), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)];
}

@end
```

It really is quite a simple mechanism.  All NSViewController really adds to any kind of controller metaphor in Cocoa is the ability to work with NSDocument and it's underlying Core Data mess sanely.

> If the view controller is the nib's “file's owner” won't I instead just be pushing the reference cycles from my current class to my view controllers? What does NSViewController do to prevent that?

NSViewController handles the retention of Top-level objects in one of the most interesting ways I've seen yet.  When it gets a reference to the array containing them, it makes a shallow-copy of the array, then `-release`s all the old array's objects.  In effect, NSViewController snatches every reference to the NIB's de-frosted objects away from NSCoder, thus guaranteeing a safe release when the array goes away in `-dealloc`.

However, when it comes to bindings, NSViewController has an internal getter for an NSProxy subclass named `NSAutounbinder`, which KVO looks for when binding and unbinding objects.  By tweaking release and providing a getter for the internal autounbinder pointer, controller classes can release themselves and their bindings without a fight.  It is absolutely not recommended that you use the implementation in CFIViewController for future OS X releases without verifying that KVO still looks for the autounbinder getter, but for most other releases, it appears to be fine.  CFIViewController provides the option to use the internal NSAutoUnbinder class as of the latest commit, thus resolving any bindings retain cycles.

Comment: This is really a lot more effort than I expected anyone to put in! Thanks for this, I will study it over. When a bounty is available I will award you some extra points for the effort.

Comment: @dreamlax Thanks for that!  I really do love peeking into the innards of AppKit and making it a little more manageable.  Feel free to use this in any future projects.

Comment: If I accept your answer now the bounty option goes away, so I've temporarily unaccepted it (but don't worry I will be back!)

Comment: Awsome code! It may be lack of coffee, however, but I can't see how `_setTopLevelObjects:` in your code makes a shallow copy of the objects. It does make one of the array, but not of the objects contained. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Monolo exactly.  It shallow copies the array, then releases the old values out from under NSCoder.  It effectively retains the array on it's end (which in Cocoa, means now it and NSCoder own it), then breaks NSCoder's link to the objects.

Comment: I now see I need to study how NSCoder and nibs work together! My reading of the comment in your code was that you wanted shallow copies of, quote: "all the objects in the array" and not (just) the array.

Comment: `NSViewController` does in fact do special memory management with respect to bindings through File's Owner, just like `NSWindowController` does. This is [obliquely documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/Cocoa/AppKitOlderNotes.html#NSViewController): "Does the same sort of memory management of top-level objects that NSWindowController does, taking the same care to prevent reference cycles when controls are bound to the nib file's owner that NSWindowController began taking in Mac OS 10.4."

Comment: And the auto-unbinder that you've left out of your version is central to that bindings management. It may not have been needed for your use, but it sounds like it will be for dreamlax's.

Comment: @KenThomases To use an internal undocumented class like NSAutoUnbinder as a reason to downvote... I left it out because I chucked a lot of the reason it existed in the first place: to keep Core Data, NSDocument, and bindings happy.  The class, as it exists now, creates no memory management problems.  Perhaps it might be different on your end, I'd appreciate a GH issue on it.

Comment: I downvoted because you said that `NSViewController` does no special memory management when it is documented to. Bindings through File's Owner cause retain cycles. I don't believe that has anything to do with ownership of the top-level objects, which is [well-documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW27). The auto-unbinder is central to breaking these cycles. I was not suggesting use of a private class. It was because without something like it, your solution is incomplete.

Comment: I have confirmed that `CFIViewController` leaks. https://github.com/CodaFi/CFIViewController/issues/1

Comment: @KenThomases I would argue that you're jumping to false conclusions based on one small test. Running under the conditions you outline, even NSViewController "leaks" like that. If you actually look through NSViewController and NSWindowController, they don't make use of their autounbinders, because NSBinder appears to handle it for them. In effect, NSViewController really does do "nothing special".  I can see how the autounbinder may have been important at some time, but not from what I can see.

Comment: @KenThomases Still, if you are so inclined to actually see what an autounbinder looks like and does with the VC, check the latest commit.

Comment: In my tests, `NSViewController` is properly released while `CFIViewController` is not. Tested on 10.6.8 for what that's worth. Since the question was about compatibility with older OSes, potential fixes of the leak by later implementations of binding doesn't help.

Comment: @KenThomases Try the auto-unbinder, then.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27251/discussion-between-codafi-and-ken-thomases)

Comment: You get the bounty for the effort you've put in. Thanks to you I have a greater understanding of how view controllers work. Despite me not being able to actually use your code I found it invaluable.